# pom.xml file showing errors when trying to add dependencies

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, deeplearning4j

Here's the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>neural</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>deeplearning4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-beta7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>nd4j-native-platform</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-beta7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I am trying to add [deeplearning4j](https://deeplearning4j.konduit.ai/config/maven)

The errors I'm getting is (I'm working in IntelliJ):

`<project" has a red underline saying "For artifact {org.example:neural:null:jar}: The version cannot be empty.`

`<artifactId>nd4j-native-platform</artifactId> <version>1.0.0-beta7</version>" is red, saying "Dependency 'org.nd4j:nd4j-native-platform:1.0.0-beta7' not found`

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you execute the build on plain command line ... ?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a maven archetype from intellij and customize that or a template project:
https://github.com/eclipse/deeplearning4j-examples/tree/master/mvn-project-template
I know link only answers aren't allowed on stackoverflow so I'll summarize a bit:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ~ Copyright (c) 2020 Konduit K.K.
  ~ Copyright (c) 2015-2019 Skymind, Inc.
  ~
  ~ This program and the accompanying materials are made available under the
  ~ terms of the Apache License, Version 2.0 which is available at
  ~ https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.
  ~
  ~ Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  ~ distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT
  ~ WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the
  ~ License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations
  ~ under the License.
  ~
  ~ SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~-->

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <!-- Group-ID, artifact ID and version of the project. You can modify these as you want -->
    <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>deeplearning4j-example-sample</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-beta7</version>

    <!-- Properties Section. Change ND4J versions here, if required -->
    <properties>
        <dl4j-master.version>1.0.0-beta7</dl4j-master.version>
        <logback.version>1.2.3</logback.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven-shade-plugin.version>2.4.3</maven-shade-plugin.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <!-- deeplearning4j-core: contains main functionality and neural networks -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>deeplearning4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${dl4j-master.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--
        ND4J backend: every project needs one of these. The backend defines the hardware on which network training
        will occur. "nd4j-native-platform" is for CPUs only (for running on all operating systems).
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>nd4j-native</artifactId>
            <version>${dl4j-master.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- CUDA: to use GPU for training (CUDA) instead of CPU, uncomment this, and remove nd4j-native-platform -->
        <!-- Requires CUDA to be installed to use. Change the version (8.0, 9.0, 9.1) to change the CUDA version -->
        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>nd4j-cuda-9.2-platform</artifactId>
            <version>${dl4j-master.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        -->

        <!-- Optional, but recommended: if you use CUDA, also use CuDNN. To use this, CuDNN must also be installed -->
        <!-- See: https://deeplearning4j.konduit.ai/config/backends/config-cudnn#using-deeplearning-4-j-with-cudnn -->
        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>deeplearning4j-cuda-9.2</artifactId>
            <version>${dl4j-master.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>



    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Maven compiler plugin: compile for Java 8 -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <!--
            Maven shade plugin configuration: this is required so that if you build a single JAR file (an "uber-jar")
            it will contain all the required native libraries, and the backends will work correctly.
            Used for example when running the following commants
            mvn package
            cd target
            java -cp deeplearning4j-examples-1.0.0-beta-bin.jar org.deeplearning4j.LenetMnistExample
            -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-shade-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                    <shadedClassifierName>bin</shadedClassifierName>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>org/datanucleus/**</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>reference.conf</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

You can use the dl4j quickstart to tell you more. Effectively, you should try to start from existing project and import as a maven project if possible. If not, create a new maven project with an archetype in intellij and customize that. Normally we use the java quickstart.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have version of your pom.xml

Change this:

```
<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>neural</artifactId>
```

To this:

```
<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>neural</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
```